# Every time the maintenance window runs the AWS-Runpatchbaseline document, we receive an execution timed out error in the systems manager run command

Tags: aws-ssm

Every time the maintenance window runs the AWS-Runpatchbaseline document, we receive an execution timed out error in the systems manager run command. We primarily encounter timeout errors on 2 standalone servers.

how to troubleshoot this issues, i could not find any error messages or logs in patch manager or in run-command ?

need some technical guidance to find out the issue or how to resolve it as i have limited knowledge on this area.

Answer (score 0):

Review the Run Command status details.

```
Open the Systems Manager console, and then choose Run Command from the navigation pane.
Choose the hyperlinked Command ID to open the Command status page.
From the Targets and outputs section, choose the hyperlinked Instance ID, and then review the output.
If the output is truncated, connect to the EC2 instance using SSH, and then navigate to the following directories to view the full error details. Note the exit status codes, and then see Troubleshooting Systems Manager Run Command for further troubleshooting steps.

/var/lib/amazon/ssm/<instance-id>/document/orchestration/<command-id>/<Plugin-name>/<Step-name>/stdout
/var/lib/amazon/ssm/<instance-id>/document/orchestration/<command-id>/<Plugin-name>/<Step-name>/stderr
```

Review the SSM Agent logs for more details about the failure:
Locate the logs in the following directories:

```
/var/log/amazon/ssm/amazon-ssm-agent.log
/var/log/amazon/ssm/errors.log
/var/log/amazon/ssm/audits/amazon-ssm-agent-audit-YYYY-MM-DD
```